# Can I have multiple states from one reducer in Redux?

Tags: javascript, redux

Let's say I have the next reducer:

```
export default (state = [], { type, payload }) => {
    switch (type) {

        case FETCH_POKEMONS:
            const objeto = {};
            payload.forEach((conexion) => {
                objeto[conexion.name] = conexion
            });
            return objeto;

        case FETCH_POKEMON:
        return { ...state, ...payload }

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

And I will have a combineReducers like this:

```
export default combineReducers({
    pokemons: pokemonReducers,
});
```

But I want to have `pokemons` state for the `FETCH_POKEMONS` actions and another state called `pokemon` for the `FETCH_POKEMON` acton. How can I derivate two states in the `combineReducers` from one reducer file?

Comment: there shouldn't be a foreach in a reducer. Your forEach should happen in the actionCreator and pass data into the reducer. The reducer should not do a lot of logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is anti pattern, the closest thing to do here would be export 2 reducers from your file, one for each use case

```
export const reducer1 = (state = [], { type, payload }) => {
    switch (type) {

        case FETCH_POKEMONS:
            const objeto = {};
            payload.forEach((conexion) => {
                objeto[conexion.name] = conexion
            });
            return objeto;

        default:
            return state
    }
}

export const reducer2 = (state = [], { type, payload }) => {
    switch (type) {

        case FETCH_POKEMON:
            return { ...state, ...payload }

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: These do not need to be two reducers. I don't see it. Pokemon and Pokemons are clearly related types of items.

Comment: They should be all under pokemon, then you can reference pokemon.all, or pokemon.selected

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you have two actions, `FETCH_POKEMONS` and `FETCH_POKEMON`, and you want them to update two different states, `pokemons` and `pokemon`, respectively.

1. If these are separate states that don't affect one-another, you'll want to create 2 reducer functions, which I'll call `pokemon` and `pokemons`, which each manage their own state and then pass those reducers into combineReducers to combine them into a single application-level reducer. I think this is more likely what you're looking for.
2. If they are not separate states but instead interconnected properties, then use a single reducer, and give the state 2 properties, pokemon and pokemons, and only update the property you are trying to update in each action (i.e. leave `state.pokemon` with its previous value when performing `FETCH_POKEMONS`.

Comment: I would not make pokemons and pokemon as two reducers. They clearly have common features. I would say if you have separate actions, you create different reducers. If you have similar grouped actions, you put them into one reducer.

Comment: I was assuming that pokemons and pokemon were just poorly chosen example names, but if they are really that similar, then I agree, they should be properties on the same state object with 1 reducer. If pokemon refers to a single item and pokemons refers to a collection that pokemon is a member of, it should also probably only store the index of that item in pokemons.

Comment: In a similar scenario where one is not using redux(so don't have access to combine reducer)  but rather using the hook useReducer. Is it bad to have two state and each have a reducer or is there a better way

Answer (score 2):

Your action creator seems fine. I am going to post one of my reducers to show how I do it.

```
import {ONIX_LOGIN_LOADING,ONIX_LOGIN_SUCCESS,ONIX_LOGIN_FAILURE,
    ONIX_CONNECTIONS_LOADING,ONIX_CONNECTIONS_SUCCESS,ONIX_CONNECTIONS_FAILURE,
    ONIX_PRODUCT_LOADING,ONIX_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,ONIX_PRODUCT_FAILURE
    } from "../actions/onix-actions";

const defaultState = {
    login:[],
    connections: [],
    product: []
};

export default function(state = defaultState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case ONIX_LOGIN_LOADING:
            return {...state, loginLoading:true};
        case ONIX_LOGIN_FAILURE:
            return {...state, loginLoading:action.isLoaded};
        case ONIX_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            return {...state, loginLoading:false, login:action.data};
        case ONIX_CONNECTIONS_LOADING:
            return {...state, connectionsLoading:true};
        case ONIX_CONNECTIONS_FAILURE:
            return {...state, connectionsLoading:false};
        case ONIX_CONNECTIONS_SUCCESS:
            return {...state, connectionsLoading:false, connections:action.data};
        case ONIX_PRODUCT_LOADING:
            return {...state, productLoading:true};
        case ONIX_PRODUCT_FAILURE:
            return {...state, productLoading:false, productTitle:false};
        case ONIX_PRODUCT_SUCCESS:
            return {...state, productLoading:false, product:action.data};
    }
    return state
}
```

I like this format, because I can call my own variables off of the state for that part of my reducer. Then in the combine reducers I have the following:

```
import books from './books';
import onix from './onix';
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    books,
    onix
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Now for all things onix I can call:
this.props.onix.login
or 
this.props.onix.productTitle 
and it will return the data I want for that part of my project. Did that answer your question?

EDIT: Here is the screenshot of my file structure for reducers

[image]

Comment: I don't understand from where do you get the `books` and `onix` values in the combineReducers

Comment: they are the name of the files I have. All of them are in the same folder, I will screenshot and update.

Comment: I added the screenshot and imports to my code sample. You can see I have a lot of reducer files, Usually one for each kind of action for my site. My code for the reducer is only the onix.js file.

Comment: But you are using multiple reducers files for multiple states, don't you? Not deriving multiple states from one reducers. Or I am not understanding?

Comment: I have one reducer for every part of my application. Like books, just handles the books part of my application. activeBook, only handles actions with a selected book. onix is a reducer that handles all of my calls to an api that handles onix api calls from publishers. IMO Pokemons and Pokemon shouldn't be separate reducers unless they have multiple methods attached and do different things. I can group a lot of actions into one reducer. My onix example has 9 actions in one reducer. The actual file has 18 total actions (actually 6, each with loading, fail and success - helps with loaders)

Comment: I am shocked by the selected "answer" - it suggests to create two reducers. You don't need a different reducer for every method in your action creator.

Comment: @PaulMiranda did you get a proper structure for your redux?